# How can I ignore properties of a subclass I dont own during serialization?

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization

I have a class `Tempo`. I can alter freely:

```
public class Tempo
{
    public Period Period { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; } // in fact int should be a T here if it matters.

    // more properties here
}
```

`Period` is a class from an external dependency I cannot alter.

```
public class Period
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    // more properties here
}
```

`Period` is a huge class with a lot of properties that I dont want to serialize. So no sweet `[JsonIgnore]` for me.
From `Period` I would like to keep only the properties `Start` and `End`.

I tried to use a `DefaultContractResolver` without success:

```
class TempoResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return props
            .Where(p => p.PropertyName != "Period") // how to filter subclass?
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I tried to use a `JsonConverter`without success:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jo = new JObject();
    var type = value.GetType();
    jo.Add("type", type.Name);
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead))
    {
        object propVal = prop.GetValue(value, null);
        if (propVal != null)
        {
            jo.Add(prop.Name,
             JToken.FromObject(propVal, serializer));  // how to filter subclass?
        }
    }
    jo.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

In both case, I am not sure how to filter `Period`. How can I ignore properties of a subclass I dont own during serialization?

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rz0EcQ)

Note:

- I use C#6
- I use JSON.NET

Comment: In your `JsonConverter`, you could substitute `Period` with a simplified class (or an anonymous object) and serialize that instead.

Comment: @John & 500 - Internal Server Error, a subset is my current solution. I am not sure it is the best way to handle it.

Comment: you could create a dto, fill the properties you need or use automapper and serialize that

Comment: @Arrangemonk Exactly my thought! I just added it to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the subclass:

```
public class Periodic
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Use the custom converter with this code:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    Periodic periodic = (Periodic)value;
    JToken t = JToken.FromObject(periodic);
    t.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Comment: If you are using a subclass, why do you need a custom converter? How does it compare to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55589055/1248177)?

Comment: The difference is the fact that you can mantain the original object this way

Comment: Ok, I get it. The idea is to keep Period in Tempo, so another dev using Tempo can benefit from the complete Period if he is using the object directly. Beside I expose only Periodic to the JSON API. I see the difference now.

Comment: Yes exactly, hope my answer helped

Comment: In the end, I might switch from my answer to yours. :)

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create strongly typed `JsonConverter` for `Period` class:

```
public class PeriodConverter : JsonConverter<Period>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Period period, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(Period.Start));
        writer.WriteValue(period.Start);
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(Period.End));
        writer.WriteValue(period.End);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override Period ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Period existingValue, bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var tempo = new Tempo
{
    Period = new Period
    {
        Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1),
        Count = 42,
        Foo = "Foo"
    },
    Value = 42
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempo, new PeriodConverter());
var regularJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempo);
```

`regularJson` will have all properties from `Period`:

> {"Period":{"Start":"2019-04-08T12:21:39.1525361+03:00","End":"2019-04-09T11:21:39.1535328+03:00","Count":42,"Foo":"Foo"},"Value":42}

and `result` only expected:

> {"Period":{"Start":"2019-04-08T12:21:39.1525361+03:00","End":"2019-04-09T11:21:39.1535328+03:00"},"Value":42}

**Update**

Code in `WriteJson` can be simplified with anonymous object:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Period period, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var token = JToken.FromObject(new {Start = period.Start, End = period.End});
    token.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Comment: [doesnt work in .netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E78DR2). I will try in local.

Comment: Worked as expected in local. I think using a dto is easier to read/use/maintain, but thank you for showing how to solve this problim with a `JsonConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use a subset of `Period`:

```
// your external dependency
public class Period
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

// your copycat with only the properties you really need
public class Periodic
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public class Tempo
{
    public Periodic Period { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var period = new Period{Count = 1, Foo = "bar", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)};
    var tempo = new Tempo{Value = 1, Period = new Periodic {Start = period.Start, End = period.End} };

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempo));
}
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLZLn2)

You can also use a library like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to handle the mapping between the external class and the copycat. For two properties, it can be a bit overkill though.

Comment: That would be my first choice as well. If you can put inheritance to use, do it.